# React-native / Splash-Screen appear when showing keyboard

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I added a splash-screen to my react native project, everything works fine exept when i open the keyboard it show briefly the splash-screen behind it.
Video :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=14ahrc-dyYnNEYAAX3iMQVwqqV6fVo_xG

### To Reproduce

create background_splash.xml in drawable with this code in it :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<layer-list 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/primary"/>
</layer-list>
```

Then add it in the styles.xml file

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">
     @drawable/background_splash
</item>
```

### Expected Behavior

The splash-screen should not display when the keyboard appears.

### Code Example

Everything is in the To Reproduce tab, you just need to add a TextInput for it to appear.

### Environment

React Native Environment Info:
System:
OS: Windows 10
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1603 v4 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 9.57 GB / 15.92 GB
Binaries:
npm: 6.4.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my app, here is my workaround.
First you have to install the module [react-native-background-color](https://github.com/goa-codebet/react-native-background-color) which allows you to set the background color of your root Activity.

After call the `setColor` method in your App.jsx (with a short timeout to avoid a "flash" immediately after splash screen) example with hooks :

```
export default function App(): Element {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
            setTimeout(() => {
                BackgroundColor.setColor("#FFFFFF");
            }, 500);
        }
    }, []);
    return <AppContainer />;
}
```

Hope this help !

Edit: improve the code with a `Platform.OS` test.

Comment: hey @jeba, i'm using this component, but when i reload the application, receive this message: "Cannot read property 'setColor' of undefined".

Comment: Hey, @M.Bertolazo Is the module correctly imported? I forked to update some dependencies if it helps you : [https://github.com/jbarnabe/react-native-background-color](https://github.com/jbarnabe/react-native-background-color)

Comment: Thanks for helping @Jeba, i was following the documentation.. i'll try with your fork later.

Comment: any way to install your version with yarn?

Comment: I don't use yarn but according to the documentation you can just use : `yarn add https://github.com/jbarnabe/react-native-background-color`

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `BackgroundColor.setColor("#00000000")`? In my app `#ffffff` still means there's a white view behind the keyboard, whereas `#00000000` seems to properly hide it (by using the alpha channel to make it transparent).

I'm not very familiar with colors on Android, so there might be something I'm missing.

Comment: works like a charm on the latest rn version(0.72.3), thank you very much sir

Answer (score 2):

These libraries (`react-native-root-view-background` & `react-native-background-color`) did not work for me probably due to being outdated, but this one worked for me flawlessly tested with  `"react-native": "~0.63.4"`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-root-view-background-color

```
import RootViewBackgroundColor from 'react-native-root-view-background-color';
 
 
// Set the Root View background color to black
RootViewBackgroundColor.setBackground(0, 0, 0, 1);
 
// Set the Root View background color to white
RootViewBackgroundColor.setBackground(255, 255, 255, 1);
```